# Jest - TypeError: response.json is not a function

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, jestjs, fetch-api

We are unit testing a React-Native application (using Jest) which does various API calls using `fetch`.

We have mocked calls to `fetch` in our API call functions in order to test them. This works well so far. We also have functions that combine these API calls and operate some logic on them.

For example, here is one function that, given a token, will get the related user's first project (`project[0]`) and return the list of items from this project.

```
export async function getAllItems(token) {
  try {
    const response = await getCurrentUser(token); // fetch called inside
    const responseJson = await response.json();
    const allItemsResp = await getAllItemsFromSpecificProject(
      token,
      responseJson.projectIds[0],
    );                                            // fetch called inside
    return await allItemsResp.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return null;
  }
}
```

Both functions `getCurrentUser` and `getAllItemsFromSpecificProject` are simple `fetch` calls and are currently mocked properly. Here one test that tries to test the `getAllItems` function:

```
it('Gets all items', async () => {
  getAccessTokenMockFetch();
  const token = await getAccessToken('usherbrooke@powertree.io', 'test!23');

  getAllItemsMockFetch();
  const items = await getAllItems(token.response.access_token);

  expect(items.response.length).toEqual(3);
});
```

For clarity, here is how `getAccessTokenMockFetch` is done. `getAllItemsMockFetch` is almost identical (with different data in the response):

```
function getAccessTokenMockFetch() {
  global.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(accepted);
    });

    return promise;
  });
}
```

where accepted contains the JSON content of a successful call. When we run this test, we get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of null
```

And we `console.log` this one in the catch:

```
TypeError: response.json is not a function
```

which explains why response is `null`. It seems the `json()` call is not understood and I don't know how to mock it. I have done tons of research on Stack Overflow and beyond, but we have found nothing that helps me understand how to solve this issue. This might indicate that I am going the wrong way about this, which is quite possible since I'm new to JavaScript, React Native, and Jest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing to try is giving it a fake `json` to call, like this:

```
const mockFetch = Promise.resolve({ json: () => Promise.resolve(accepted) });
global.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => mockFetchPromise);
```

Comment: In this case I'm getting only data passed in resolve from **mockImplementation**, I want to get response from real api and test that response if getting all required items in API how can I do that using **fetch**?  @emily-coleman

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where I was getting this error while creating jest unit test.Here is my solution to creating `helper` function to create mock response.

```js
function createMockResponse(
    body: any,
    status: number,
    statusText: string
  ): Response {
    return {
      ok: status >= 200 && status < 300,
      status,
      statusText,
      headers: {
        get: (headerName: string) => {
          if (headerName === 'content-type') {
            return 'application/json'
          }
          return null
        },
      },
      json: async () => body,
    } as unknown as Response
  }
```